# EDT editor - a modern approach?

Tags: text-editor, edt, vms

I used the EDT editor on VMS very long time ago.  Is there modern implementation of this excellent text editor available?  If so, are there source codes?  Maybe it is circumvented by Emacs and Vim?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.atl.lmco.com/projects/csim/gui/edt/

According to the [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227155339/http://www.atl.lmco.com/projects/csim/gui/edt/), this is now at

http://edt-text-editor.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to chase down SEDT  [(See link)](http://www.texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SEDT).  I remember this one from MS-DOS days.  I don't know if anyone has reimplemented it for windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an OpenVMS plugin for Netbeans which adds the EDT keypad to the Netbeans editor - gives the best of both worlds.
http://h71000.www7.hp.com/openvms/products/ips/netbeans/distnb.html

Only problem is that it is for older versions of Netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

You can try GNU Emacs EDT-mode:https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/edt.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/394800) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)